# Как сделать default картинку, пока не подгрузится необходимая

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Есть список элементов, лежащий в базе, картинки к элементам хранятся на облаке, необходимо что бы при переходе к списку элементов изначально отображалась одна картинка дефолтная, но как только подгрузится из облака, либо нет ( на пример при отсутствии коннекта) отображалась одна стандартная
использую MVVM патерн, и три слоя ДДД:

- Application Layer
- Domain Layer
- Infrastructure layer

Пишется все именно на  Xamarin Forms

Comment: Отображать стандартную картинку если нет нормальной - это чисто задача View, решение - например триггер, срабатывающий по значению null

Comment: @Андрей будем сейчас пробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Задать картинку по умолчанию
2 - Настроить Binding, создать event (Action/EventHandler)
3 - При подгрузке изображение из внешнего источника через подписку на событие обновить по связке данную картинку.

логика в том, что пока событие не произошло идет отображение стандартной картинки, при его наступлении обновить источник.